# Right way to send LocalStorage to server side php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I´m writing an application using html5 localstorage. It´s a dinamic questionary witch is managed by a javascript engine. I need to storage the answers in a mysql database running php on the server side.

The solution i used was create a form with hidden inputs witch is dinamically created and filled by that javascript engine, so I post the form to server. Its working fine, but i´m wondering if that is correct.

There is a best way to do this ?

Comment: Don't know if it's the best solution but personnaly I'll encode it in json then use an ajax call to send it to the server. Edit: seem's this is a good solution given the Doge's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize all your data into a string, such as with `JSON.stringify` and send it to the server with an AJAX request.

Form-encoding can be problematic for some values, such as when you want to send an empty list.

Comment: Thanks Doge, I will use JSON instead.